# How do you represent different instrument of the same section alternating a part?

Tags: notation, sheet-music

I've composed a passage with an upper tonic pedal point in the flutes. Problem is that the pedal point lasts 51 bars in an adagio tempo(roughly 2 minutes), and nobody would be able to play a continuous note that long on the flute without some kind of lung enhancement superpower. My solution is to have the three flutes alternate for 2-bar periods, giving any given flutist 4 bars of rest before entering for 2 bars. But how do you notate that? Writing on the score "The three flutes are to alternate this note for 2 bar periods" isn't a very elegant solution. The closest thing I can think of is divisi, but divisi is only used for multiple notes at once. Is there any concise way to tell a given part to split the part amongst the instruments in this way?

Comment: So the three flutists will be sharing a single score (as opposed to each having their own part)?

Comment: Could you please try to write parts that don't make the performers hate you?  Yes you've at least avoided asking them to keel over from lack of breath, but they're dying of boredom.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo Tell that to Bruckner: https://imslp.org/wiki/Symphony_No.7_in_E_major%2C_WAB_107_(Bruckner%2C_Anton)      It's to build a lot of tension, as it usually is when using a pedal point. The rest of the harmony should compensate.

Comment: @oprenStein Which movement? Have you got a bar-number? I'd like to see why Bruckner writes it.

Comment: You *will* need at least two flute staves to express this at all, and at that point you might as well just write the three parts on three staves and remove all doubt.

Comment: Further to @Aaron's point:  having two parts on a single staff in a wind/brass part is annoying.  Having three parts on a staff is actively hard to read, particularly for the middle player.  So this is only really a problem in the conductor's score, because you're going to give the flute players their own individual parts, right? Right?

Comment: I see nothing inelegant about that single sentence which perfectly conveys the composer's intent.

Comment: Could you not use a call and response?

Comment: @OprenStein: Yes I understand the musical purpose, and some composers have not treated their performers nicely, but people are more likely to play your work when it is interesting to play for all the performers (which is not the same thing as being interesting to listen to).

Comment: @AlexanderWoo I see where you're coming from, and I understand that some flutists might be annoyed at not getting melodies for two minutes. However, I feel that the upper pedal point is necessary to build the amount of tension that I want. Also, the flutes will get many melodies and interesting passages later on. If I write as much as I think I will, the pedal point comprises about 7% of the piece, and there are a couple variations that don't include the flute, but overall, the flutes will play a lot(even getting a flute chorale and a solo variation!) So I think it's made up for.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The way I've handled this situation is choirs, where one section has to sustain a note beyond a single breath, the section leader has assigned divisi and breathing points.

It will be obvious from your score that the note can't be sustained by a single player, and since there will be more than one flutist, they should be able to figure out a scheme for themselves. That would only require a simple note from you: "staggered breathing" or something to that effect.

Comment: I've most commonly seen "staggered breathing" for long notes like this.

Comment: @Dekkadeci That's exactly the term. Thanks.

Comment: Because different players have different lung capacities, and some may enter or exit more smoothly than others, a musical group who can experiment to find what works best for them is apt to yield a smoother sound than a composer who has no way of knowing about different players' abilities.

Answer (score 5):

> divisi is only used for multiple notes at once

That's not in fact correct.  *Divisi* simply means the section divides.  They do different things; it doesn't have to be playing multiple notes at once.

Write *divisi* and then every two measures write 1st, 2nd, 3rd, and then write *simile.*  Consider giving each player two measures plus one beat, overlapping with the following player, to show that this is supposed to simulate a single long tone.

You can look to other orchestral pedal points in the literature for inspiration, for example the fugue at the end of the third movement of Brahms Requiem:

Answer (score 4):

Aaron, phoog and Dekkadeci are wise beyond their years.

I don't know the tempo, register or key but an arrangement like this has all three flutes sounding almost constantly:

[image]

(This is pretty much what Brahms does in the Requiem.) If the flutes are very exposed you may need to ask for an imperceptible attack on each note. (I believe youngsters call this a *fade-in*.)